# Root Android x86 VirtualBox

Tags: rooting, 4.3-jelly-bean, android-x86, virtualbox

I have installed Android-x86, version 4.3 Jellybean iso image into virtual box, and want to run some applications that require root privileges.

Is there any way to root it?

Comment: I'm just sitting in the same boat. There's a guide + script on [How to root Android x86 4.3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2390619) at XDA, but it didn't work out for me (apparently neither for some others on the thread), while there are positive reports as well. You might be lucky with it. If so, it would be interesting to know what image you're using, and where to obtain it, in order to cross-check (it might be differences in builds).